# Restify: Set default formatter

Tags: restify

Also asked in official Restify repo: [#1224](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1224)

Hi,

Is it possible to have one default formatter that can handle any accept type that is not defined.

For Example:

```
restify.createServer({
    formatters: {
        'application/json': () => {},
        // All other requests that come in are handled by this, instead of throwing error
        'application/every-thing-else': () => {}
    }
});
```

Comment: How can you expect to not have to code this when you are trying to return custom models? The default formatter is for application/octet-stream, if that helps.

Comment: I wasn't clear before. Updated the question. I want a single formatter that can handle anything other than restifies default formatter list.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. In my case all the mime types are just JSON outputs with different set of properties.

Comment: Ah. I think a better title would be "Set default formatter", skip all the first part of your question and just use the restify tag.

Answer (score 0):

By all appearances, this is impossible.  Since the formatters are stored in a dictionary, there is no way to create a key that matches every input (that would kind of defeat the point of a dictionary anyway...) The only way to accomplish this kind of thing outside of JSON would be with a regular expression, and regular expressions don't work with JSON.

Here is a program I wrote to test this.

```
var restify = require("restify");

var server = restify.createServer({
    formatters: {
        'application/json': () => { console.log("JSON") },
        "[\w\W]*": () => { console.log("Everything else") } // Does not work
    }
});

server.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Root");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "not/supported");
    res.send(200, {"message": "this is a test"});
    next()
});

server.listen(10000);
```

Also here is a link to the documentation on this in case you can find some hint that I couldn't see.
[Restify documentation](http://restify.com/#content-negotiation)

Comment: I may have overlooked, but I can't find the documentation about the key being a regular expression. Is it documented?

Comment: It is not, regular expressions don't work with JSON.  I gave my test code to show what I tried.  I wanted you to have it in case you wanted to test it yourself.